# echo input value by id woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, echo

I have a custom input for admin page in woocommerce:

```
function wc_rent_product_field()
{
  woocommerce_wp_text_input(array('id' => 'rent_price',
    'class' => 'wc_input_price short',
    'label' => __('Rent price', 'woocommerce') . ' (' . get_woocommerce_currency_symbol() . ')',
    'description' => __('enter to cancel "0"',
      'woocommerce'),));
}
```

How can I echo it's value on product page

Answer (score 0):

```
$rentPrice = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'rent_price', true );
```

and echo it